# Baseball card collecting probability and use of Markov

Tags: probability

A young baseball fan wants to collect a complete set of 260 baseball cards.
The baseball cards are available in a completely random fashion, one per package of chewing gum.

What is the probability that the fan gets the full set by buying at most 261 boxes of chewing
gums?

Now if I were to follow the coupon's collector, the expected number of 'draws' for this problem would be $1611$

Should I then apply Markov's inequality to bound the probability?

Comment: The general sort of problem asked about here is known as the [Coupon Collectors Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem_).  That said, your answer is way too high.  in $263$ trials you will get many, many duplicates so the true probability here is quite near n=$0$.

Comment: Could you explain the reasoning that led you to the ${259 \over 260}$ answer?

Comment: Do you mean that the fan gets the full set either on the 260 box or the 261 box? If so, this sounds more like the birthday problem than the coupon collector.

Comment: It's at most, so it could either on 260th or 261st

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let X be the box bought on which we get the complete set of cards.
That is, we don't get a complete set until we have bought box X.

$$P(X = 260) = \frac{260}{260}\frac{259}{260}...\frac{1}{260}=\frac{260!}{260^{260}}$$

$$P(X = 261) = \binom{260}{1}\frac{260}{260}\frac{259}{260}...\frac{2}{260}\frac{259}{260}\frac{1}{260}=\frac{260!(259)}{260^{260}}$$

Summing up the probabilities gives you the required answer.

Comment: Wouldn't this yield huge numbers?

Comment: No. Because each of the ignoring the $\frac{260}{260}$ term, all of the other terms are less than 1. Even if you multiply by 259, the probability will still be near 0 as lulu mentioned. Try multiplying the terms using a calculator. You will see that it is a very small number.

Comment: Also, the coupon collector problem asks about the probability that you will need more than k trials to get the complete set. Your original problem asks about the probability that you will need at most k trials to get the complete set. For a set of 260 cards, the expected number of trials would be close to 2085. So, there is a high probability that you will need more than 261 trials to get the complete set.